# How to use Array.prototype.includes(null) with strict null check enabled?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have enabled strict null checking in my Typescript project. I have a function `foo` which takes an optional argument. Inside the function body, I want to check whether that optional argument is given.

I am using `![null, undefined].includes(myOptionalArgument)` to do that but the linter is complaining.

```js
enum MyEnum {
  KeyA,
  KeyB,
}

function foo(myOptionalArgument?: MyEnum): boolean {
  // I am seeing the following lint warning:
  //
  // Passing nullable argument to function that expects non nullable `eslintstrict-null-checks/all`
  const valueIsGiven = ![null, undefined].includes(myOptionalArgument);

  // Do more stuff
  ...
}
```

---

When I go to the `Array.prototype.includes` definition (in VSCode `typescript/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts`), I could see the following:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    /**
     * Determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.
     * @param searchElement The element to search for.
     * @param fromIndex The position in this array at which to begin searching for searchElement.
     */
    includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
}
```

Since `searchElement` is not optional I can understand the warning I am seeing. However, I am curious as to how we can check `null` or `undefined` in an array when we enable strict null checking.

---

I would also like to find a solution to my problem. I know I can simple do something like below.

```js
const valueIsGiven = !(myOptionalArgument === null || myOptionalArgument === undefined);
```

But I usually prefer using my first approach because it seems more elegant.

---

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: 1: Generally people write `myOptionalArgument == null` since the loose equality of `==` is exactly the `null`-or-`undefined` check you're trying to do.  I don't think I've *ever* seen anyone write `[null, undefined].includes(myOptionalArgument)`.

Comment: 2: Do you have the `--strictNullChecks` TypeScript option on?  Or is it just an eslint rule?

Comment: @jcalz I don't have `strictNullChecks` option set on the Typescript compiler. This is just for the eslint parser. Earlier, I used to have another restriction for the double equality operator `==`. That is why I am used to writing the check for `null` and `undefined` in this way. Looking back at the code, your suggestion seems perfect because now we allow loose equality. Thank you for the quick answer. :-)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to check if an array actually includes `null` or `undefined` with this configuration?

Comment: I have no experience with eslint's strict null checks, so I can't help here, sorry.